# Spreadsheet excel - how to create a button that does multiple formulae`

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Hello in my spreadsheet i'd like to add a caluclate on and off button for these cells: http://prntscr.com/e6rbir

the formula for male total is: `=COUNTIF(E:E, "M")`
the forumla for female total is: `=COUNTIF(E:E, "F")`
the formula for other total is: `=COUNTIF(E:E, "O")`
the formula for total is: `=SUM(H2:H4)`

I would like to seperate buttons, one that says calculate on and one that says calculate off.

How would i go about doing this?

Comment: meaning, if you click a button, the calculation shows? Do you need it to be a button? What if a cell simply said "Calculate?" and if the cell next to it was "Yes", they showed?

Comment: No i mean like a checkbox button that can be clicked and it would do the formulae in those above cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a No VBA at all solution and no buttons:

In I2, place an "X" for On and place the following formula in Male

```
=If(I2="X",COUNTIF(E:E, "M"),"")
```

Follow suit for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

How about this macro to show your formula:

```
Sub AddFormulasOn()
  cells(2,8).Formula = "=COUNTIF(E:E, ""M"")"
  cells(3,8).Formula = "=COUNTIF(E:E, ""F"")"
  cells(4,8).Formula = "=COUNTIF(E:E, ""O"")"
  cells(5,8).Formula = "=SUM(H2:H4)"
End Sub
```

And this macro to remove the formulas:

```
Sub AddFormulasOn()
  cells(2,8).Value = ""
  cells(3,8).Value = ""
  cells(4,8).Value = ""
  cells(5,8).Value = ""
End Sub
```

You can also combine it into one macro that does both:

```
Sub AddFormulasOn()
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("H2:H5")) = 0 Then
  cells(2,8).Formula = "=COUNTIF(E:E, ""M"")"
  cells(3,8).Formula = "=COUNTIF(E:E, ""F"")"
  cells(4,8).Formula = "=COUNTIF(E:E, ""O"")"
  cells(5,8).Formula = "=SUM(H2:H4)"
Else
  cells(2,8).Value = ""
  cells(3,8).Value = ""
  cells(4,8).Value = ""
  cells(5,8).Value = ""
End if
End Sub
```